# Defining the Greatest Common Divisor using Symbolic Notation

Tags: logic, divisibility

I am trying to write the definition of greatest common divisor using symbolic notation. Here is my current attempt:

$d = gcd(m,n) \Leftrightarrow d \in Z \wedge max(d | m \wedge d | n)$

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try to say what you are saying on the right-hand side: $$d = \gcd(m, n) \iff \Big((d\in \mathbb Z \land d\mid m \land d\mid n) \land \forall d' \in \mathbb Z\left((d'\mid m \land d'\mid n) \rightarrow d' \leq d\right)\Big)$$

Comment: Does the small right arrow suggest Implication?

Comment: Yes, it does. I often use that instead of $\implies$ in logic.

Comment: What this is saying, in "loglish" is that there is an integer divisor $d$ that divides m and that divides n, and for all integers d' that divides m and divides n, d' is less than or equal to d.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for commenting. I didn't have it originally, then second-guessed myself and added it. I should have stuck with what I had! (Now restored to original)

Comment: @amWhy: Right up your alley! +1

Comment: Why is $d\in \mathbb Z$ and not $d\in \mathbb N$? Can $\gcd$ be negative?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative definition: $\;\gcd(m,n)\;$ is the (unique) non-negative number that satisfies
$$
\langle \forall d \in \mathbb Z :: d \mid \gcd(m,n) \;\equiv\; d \mid m \:\land\: d \mid n \rangle
$$
See [some answers of mine which use this definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+user%3A11994+gcd).